# Spin-2 operators from metric fluctuations in the AdS/CFT

Tags: metric-tensor, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, supergravity

This is a computational question. I am pretty sure that there is a simple explanation, and something obvious that I am missing but I cannot figure it out.

I want to add that this is not meant to be a "check my computation" question. I am just trying to understand what underlying principles and/or assumptions I am failing to impose in order to obtain the correct results.

I am giving some context hoping that other members can benefit from the discussion. Though the example here is specific to $\mathrm{AdS}_3$ metric perturbations, the issue is more general as I describe in the end.

By virtue of the AdS/CFT, the spectrum of the dual gauge invariant operators is encoded in the linearized fluctuations of the corresponding supergravity background. This is a highly non-trivial task and the full half-BPS spectra are known only in a handful of cases; $\mathrm{AdS}_5 \times \mathrm{S}^5$, $\mathrm{AdS}_3 \times \mathrm{S}^3$ and $\mathrm{AdS}_3 \times \mathrm{S}^3 \times \mathrm{S}^3 \times \mathrm{S}^1$.

Be that as it may, in 2011 Bachas and Estes wrote a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2800) in which they examined spin-2 operators by studying metric fluctuations. One of the main results of said paper is in supergravity backgrounds in which the fluxes do not have components along the AdS subspace, the equation describing the linearized fluctuations of the metric assumes a particularly simple form.

Since then, there have been many beautiful papers that utilize this idea in the context of the AdS/CFT. Since my question, as I have already mentioned, is computational I am providing an explicit example.

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.14390), the author studied metric perturbations in the context of $\tfrac{1}{4}$-BPS AdS$_3$/CFT$_2$. The metric of that solution is given by

$$
\begin{equation}
ds^2_{10} = e^{-\tfrac{\phi}{2}} f_1 ds^2_{\mathrm{AdS}_3} + \hat{G}_{ab}dz^a dz^b. 
\end{equation}
$$

The above is of the form $\mathrm{AdS}_3 \times \mathcal{I}_{\rho} \times S^2 \times \mathrm{CY}_2$. In the following we choose $\mathrm{CY}_2 = \mathrm{T}^4$ as is the case in the paper. A little bit more explicitly to have a better grasp on the geometry:

$
\begin{equation}
ds^2_{10} = e^{-\tfrac{\phi}{2}} \frac{u}{\sqrt{h_4h_8}} ds^2_{\mathrm{AdS}_3} + e^{-\tfrac{\phi}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{h_4h_8}}{u} d\rho^2 + e^{-\tfrac{\phi}{2}} \frac{u \sqrt{h_4 h_8}}{4h_4h_8 + {u^{\prime}}^2} (dw^2_1 + \sin^2 w_1 dw^2_2) + e^{-\tfrac{\phi}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{h_4}{h_8}} (d\theta^2_1+d\theta^2_2+d\theta^2_3+d\theta^2_4),
\end{equation}
$

where in the above the functions $u, h_4, h_8$ as well as the dilaton are functions of the internal coordinate $\rho$.

We want to consider the transverse and traceless fluctuations along the AdS part of the geometry. We write
$$
\begin{equation}
ds^2_{10} = e^{-\tfrac{\phi}{2}} f_1 (ds^2_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}+h_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}) + \hat{G}_{ab}dz^a dz^b.
\end{equation}
$$
We write the fluctuations that appear above as
$$
\begin{equation}
h_{\mu \nu} = h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu}(x) \psi(z) \equiv h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu} \psi,
\end{equation}
$$
and thus we are separating the dependence of the fluctuations. The transverse, traceless part, $[tt]$, satisfies
\begin{equation}
\nabla^{\mu} h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu} = g^{\mu \nu} h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu} = 0,
\end{equation}
and also
$$
\begin{equation}
\square_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu}=(M^2-2)h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu},
\end{equation}
$$
where we have denoted the Laplacian of AdS$_3$ by $\square_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}$.

Following the work by [Bachas-Estes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2800), we know that the linearized Einstein equations reduce the following Laplace equation in ten-dimensions:

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_{M} (\sqrt{g} g^{MN} \partial_N h_{\mu \nu}) = 0. 
\end{equation}
$$
In the above $\sqrt{g}$ is the square root of the absolute value of the determinant of the ten-dimensional metric, and the capital indices take values in the ten-dimensional target spacetime. More explicitly, for the metric that we consider here we have
$$
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{g} = (e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{3/2}\sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}}\sqrt{\hat{g}}
\end{equation}
$$

We can expand the Laplacian to the non-compact and internal bits:
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_{\mu} (\sqrt{g} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\nu} h_{\mu \nu}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_{a} (\sqrt{g} g^{ab} \partial_b h_{ab}) = 0. 
\end{equation}
$$
We use the decomposition $h_{\mu \nu} = h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu} \psi$ and the conditions that $h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu}$ satisfies to the evaluate the above explicitly. We have for the first bit:

$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_{\mu} (\sqrt{g} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\nu} h_{\mu \nu}) = \frac{(e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}}\sqrt{\hat{g}}}\partial_{\mu} ((e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{3/2} \sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}}\sqrt{\hat{g}}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}h^{[tt]}_{\mu\nu})\psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}}} \partial_{\mu} ( \sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\nu}h^{[tt]}_{\mu\nu})\psi = \square_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu}\psi=(M^2-2)h^{[tt]}_{\mu \nu} \psi,
\end{equation}
$

having used the fact that: $(e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{3/2}, \sqrt{\hat{g}}$ and $\psi$ do not depend on the $x^{\mu}$-coordinates.

We can work in the same vein for the other piece of the ten-dimensional Laplace equation. We have

$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_{a} (\sqrt{g} g^{ab} \partial_b h_{ab}) = \frac{(e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}}\sqrt{\hat{g}}} \partial_{a}( (e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{3/2} \sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}}\sqrt{\hat{g}}g^{ab}\partial_{b}\psi)h^{[tt]}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{(e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{\hat{g}}} \partial_a ((e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{3/2} \sqrt{\hat{g}}g^{ab}\partial_{b}\psi)h^{[tt]}_{\mu\nu},
\end{equation}
$

having used the fact that $\sqrt{g_{\mathrm{AdS}_3}}$ and $h^{[tt]}_{\mu\nu}$ do not depend on the internal coordinates $z$.

Now, we can collect the above results and we have explicitly:

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{(e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{\hat{g}}} \partial_a ((e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{3/2} \sqrt{\hat{g}}g^{ab}\partial_{b}\psi) = -(M^2-2) \psi.
\end{equation}
$$

The above result is very different from what I should have obtained, see eq.(15) on page 6 from the [relevant paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.14390) which I am reproducing here for the reader's convenience:

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{(e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{\hat{g}}} \partial_a ((e^{-\phi/2}f_1)^{3/2} \sqrt{\hat{g}}g^{ab}\partial_{b}\psi) = -M^2 \psi.
\end{equation}
$$

Now, the immediate reaction is that perhaps this is a typo, but similar studies follow this pattern with the difference of powers from the metric factors and also are missing the factor of $-2$ from the RHS, see for example similar studies performed in [AdS$_5$/CFT$_4$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07109) eq.(2.12) on page 5 and also [AdS$_6$/CFT$_5$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11914) eq.(3.5) on page 4.

Any ideas/hints?